# Grover's search for solving TSP

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming, grovers-algorithm

Consider the modified version of the Traveling Salesman Problem where you are searching for a path of length less than some $k$. We can solve this problem using Grover's search where we encode each one of the possible paths as a quantum state and then search for the ones that have length less than $k$.

The oracle for this problem is supposed to add the weights of the edges in the given path, check if the total weight is less than $k$ and output 1 if it is the case. How can one construct an oracle for this problem? Is there a practical implementation? How and where to encode the weights of the edges?

Comment: Hi cssstyler, does there need to be something uniquely quantum in your question?  Could you not use the standard Karp reduction to $\mathsf{SAT}$, satisfiability?

Comment: So you suggest that we can reduce it to satisfiability and then solve it since the oracle for that is obvious. But in that case I wondered if we could write an oracle without using a reduction.

Comment: Have you seen this repository https://github.com/Naphann/Solving-TSP-Grover ?